# Saving command-line parameter value to text file in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In addition to usual install tasks I need to get the value of the command line parameter (for example `/MyParam=XXX`) and then copy the parameter value (`XXX`) to a txt file in the app folder. So far I tried the code below but I don't know how to properly pass the parameter value to the code procedure.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion overwritereadonly; \
    AfterInstall: SaveParam('{param:MyParam}');

[Code]
procedure SaveParam(S: String);
begin
  if S<>'' then
  begin
    SaveStringToFile('{app}\file.txt', 'Value=' + S, False);
  end;
end;
```

In short, when I run the installer by `MyApp.exe /MyParam=XXX` I expect the  `Value=XXX` text would be added into the `file.txt` file. Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start here: [Is it possible to accept custom command line parameters with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618257/850848#48349992)

Other things you need to know:

- You have to [`ExpandConstant`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) the `{app}` in the file path.
- You should use [`CurStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) to trigger the writing. Using `AfterInstall` of an unrelated file works too, but it's more like a hack.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Value: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Value := ExpandConstant('{param:MyParam}');
    if (Value <> '') or CmdLineParamExists('MyParam') then
    begin
      Log('Writing "' + Value + '" to file...');
      SaveStringToFile(
        ExpandConstant('{app}\file.txt'), 'Value=' + Value, False);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

- For `CmdLineParamExists`, see my answer linked at the top.
- Note that `SaveStringToFile` is not Unicode-safe. For Unicode files, see [Create a UTF8 file without BOM with Inno Setup (Unicode version)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36876001/850848).